# Calculating the induced norms of a $2 \times 2$ matrix from defintion.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Given $ ||A||_p = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{||Ax||_p}{||x||_p}$ and

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate $||A||_1$, $||A||_2$, and $||A||_\infty$.

Now I know how to calculate all these norms in practice, but what this question seems to be implying, is that I calculate the norms starting from the general definition of the induced matrix norms, and this is where I'm at a loss, is there a standard procedure to go about calculating them this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do $\|A\|_1$ and you will do the rest.

Let $x=\binom{x_1}{x_2}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, by definition $\|x\|_1 = |x_1| + |x_2|$. Now $$Ax = \binom{x_1 + 2x_2}{2x_2}$$ and again by definition $\|Ax\|_1 = |x_1| + 2|x_2| +2|x_2| = |x_1|+4|x_2|$.

Therefore,
$$\|A\|_1 = \sup_{x\not = 0} \frac{|x_1|+4|x_2|} {|x_1|+|x_2|}.$$

On one hand this is less or equal to $4$, because we can replace $|x_1|$ in the nominator by $4|x_1|$ and get a higher value. On the other hand if we take $x=(0,1)$ we get $\|Ax\|_1/\|x\|_1 = 4/1 = 4$. Therefore, $\|A\|_1=4$.

Comment: I see, thanks ,I still have some difficulty understanding working with supremums, I think you made a slight arithmetic mistake when doing the matrix multiplication, I believe the 1-norm is 4. Then for the infinity norm following the, I took x = (1,1), because I believe this is the vector which maximises the expression, correct? It gives the correct answer of 3, however I'm not sure if my reasoning is fully correct.

Comment: Right I forgot to multiply by $2$, now it is correct, thanks!. What you did is OK, but it will not give you the solution you want. If you set $x=(1,1)$ you will get $\frac{5}{2}=2.5$ (not 3?), but then this is not the maximal value (the maximal value is $4$). So you can not just plug in any $x$, you have to plug in the $x$ that will give the maximal value. In my solution I have also argued that the maximal value must be at most $4$, which was very important for the complete answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am discussing my reasoning for the infinity norm, not the 1-norm,  for the infinity norm, I had $ \sup_{x \neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_{\infty}}{||x||_\infty} = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{||(x_1 + 2x_2, 2x_2)||_{\infty}}{||x||_{\infty}}$ which I believe is the same as maximising $||(x_1 + 2x_2, 2x_2)||_{\infty}$ subject to $||x||_{\infty} = 1$, which is why I chose (1,1).

Comment: Ah ok, yes this is great, all you need to do now is to show that for every $x$ (not just $(1,1)$) you have that $\|Ax\|_{\infty}/\|x\|_\infty$ must be less or equal to $3$. This will guarantee that $x=(1,1)$ is the maximal value. Hint: use the fact that $x_1+2x_2 \leq 3 \max\{x_1,x_2\}$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it, for the 2-norm this looks like it will be quite tricky, perhaps Lagrange Multipliers would be helpful?